# Problem with Publish app for the webOS from Avalonia

Tags: .net, .net-core, web-applications, avalonia

I have a cross-platform Avalonia app. In my case, I need to publish the browser.app in the local folder using the framework-dependent deployment mode. However, I'm encountering the following error: 'Error: $(MicrosoftNetCoreAppRuntimePackDir)='', and cannot find %(ResolvedRuntimePack.PackageDirectory)='. One of these needs to be set to a valid path. I don't understand where I should set this path and why the program doesn't recognize it. My task is to publish the Avalonia browser.app so that it functions like a website.

I use Jetbrains RIder IDE on the macOS

I have tried updating the .NET version and have also read the official Avalonia documentation, but it hasn't helped me resolve the issue.